# While studying NodeJs i got "cannot get 'address' " problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

While studying Nodejs i got "cannot get 'address' " problem
I started studying Nodejs few days ago...

I tried to make my local server and devided files by its usage.

in my node Project, there is

1.index (which is main file)
2.routes
3.routers' folder(including global router, courses router ... etc)
4.controllers' folder(including global controller, courses router ... etc)
5.babelrc
6.package.json

This is my index.js

```
    import express from "express";
    import routes from "./routes";
    import globalRouter from "./routers/globalRouter";
    import coursesRouter from "./routers/coursesRouter";
    // import apiRouter from "./routers/apiRouter";
    // import apiV1Router from "./routers/apiV1Router";
    // import apiV2Router from "./routers/apiV2Router";

    const app = express();

    app.use(routes.home, globalRouter);
    app.use(routes.courses, coursesRouter);
    //app.use(routes.apiDocumentation, apiRouter);
    //app.use(routes.apiV1, apiV1Router);
    //app.use(routes.apiV2, apiV2Router);

    // app.use(routes.remove, apiV2Router);
    // app.use(routes.edit, apiV2Router);

    // Codesanbox does not need PORT :)
    app.listen(() => console.log(`Listening!`));
```

and this is my globalRouter.js

```
    import express from "express";
    import routes from "../routes";
    import {
      home,
      join,
      login,
      confirmAccount
    } from "../controllers/globalController";

    const globalRouter = express.Router();

    globalRouter.get(routes.home, home);
    globalRouter.get(routes.join, join);
    globalRouter.get(routes.login, login);
    globalRouter.get(routes.confirmAccount, confirmAccount);

    export default globalRouter;
```

and this is my globalController

```
    export const home = (req, res) => res.send("home");
    export const join = (req, res) => res.send("join");
    export const login = (req, res) => res.send("login");
    export const confirmAccount = (req, res) => res.send("confirm account");
```

my coursesRouter

```
    import express from "express";
    import routes from "../routes";
    import { courses, _new, mine } from "../controllers/coursesController";

    const coursesRouter = express.Router();

    coursesRouter.get(routes.courses, courses);
    coursesRouter.get(routes.new, _new);
    coursesRouter.get(routes.mine, mine);

    export default coursesRouter;
```

my coursesController

```
    export const courses = (req, res) => res.send("courses");
    export const _new = (req, res) => res.send("new");
    export const mine = (req, res) => res.send("mine");
```

my routes.js

```
    //Global
    const HOME = "/";
    const JOIN = "/join";
    const LOGIN = "/login";
    const CONFIRM_ACCOUNT = "/confirm-account";

    //Courses
    const COURSES = "/courses";
    const NEW = "/courses/new";
    const MINE = "/courses/mine";

    //Api
    const API = "/api";
    const API_DOCUMENTATION = "/api/documentation";

    //Api V1
    const API_V1 = "/api/v1";
    const API_V1_BUY = "/api/v1/buy";
    const API_V1_REFUND = "/api/v1/refund";

    //Api V2
    const API_V2 = "api/v2";
    const API_V2_REMOVE = "/api/v2/remove";
    const API_V2_EDIT = "/api/v2/edit";

    const routes = {
      home: HOME,
      join: JOIN,
      login: LOGIN,
      confirmAccount: CONFIRM_ACCOUNT,
      courses: COURSES,
      new: NEW,
      mine: MINE,
      api: API,
      apiDocumentation: API_DOCUMENTATION,
      apiV1: API_V1,
      apiV2: API_V2,
      apiV1Buy: API_V1_BUY,
      apiV1Refund: API_V1_REFUND,
      apiV2Remove: API_V2_REMOVE,
      apiV2Edit: API_V2_EDIT
    };

    export default routes;
```

I don't think there are problems with routes but...

when I solely tested global router, 
it worked((ex)"localhost:4000/" result:home or "local host:4000/join" result:join) 
but when i relieved comment on courses router and search "localhost:4000/courses" it didn't... and throw result "cannot get /courses"..

I need help to fix the problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main Router, you route every request starting with "/courses" to the courses router, and the courses router will answer requests that match "/courses" itself, so your API endpoint is actually available under "/courses/courses". You might want to change the path in the courses router to `.get("/"` ...

Comment: holymoly...! thanks a lot!!! Can I ask question one more? So i change code to ```app.use(routes.home, coursesRouter);```
and it worked well but when i relieved comment on ```app.use(routes.api, apiRouter);```  TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object had occured... routes.api is "/api"